# Ideal solution to make class with several properties thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a class that represents a table in a datebase with each property of the class mapping to a column in the database. This class has several properties right now, 57 in fact. I need to share a list of these devices between a few threads.

My first question is what type of collection should I use that is best like a list to share between the threads. From looking in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace, I believe a ConcurrentBag best suits my need, but if there are any other recommendations, I am open to it.

Secondly, the values assigned to the properties of my class will change over time. I have seen examples of putting locks in the get and set blocks of the properties, but I wanted to know if there was a cleaner way than declaring 57 different lock variables and putting locks all in my code.

Comment: 57 properties in one class? And it doesn't seem to you it's clearly a bad OOP decision? Oh man... You should definitely fix this first.

Comment: @walther well, if it is *only* a class representing a table, I wouldn't be that rude ;) if this is a business-model, I would definitely go for a massive refactoring!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Yes the table has a lot of columns that I have to represent. I wouldn't under normal circumstances make a class with so many properties.

Comment: @Justin why do you have to synchronize a table-class?? isn't that more the responsibility of a manager, eg repository, or the DAL itself (if following ACID)?

Comment: Can you explain why you need locks?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, I aim only to make it easier for him. Even if this was a representation of a table, the design is still bad and he should refactor the SQL table as well. 57 is a huge number for a single object and I somewhat can't believe that there can't be done any optimization to it.

Comment: @walther I completely understand your concerns, and it was a very good idea to mention your troubles with that design (in fact, I am sharing the same). Nevertheless, even when doing massive refactoring there still will be 57 properties floating around, which are in the need to be synchronized ...

Comment: @Justin Please explain what "thread safe" mean to you in relation to this post. Individual updates of all reference members are "thread safe" by itself (as pointer-sized types are always atomically updated) - so there is no need to have locks in this case. I.e. do you have any fields of struct type in you 57 fields list? OR are there any requirements to prevent update of some field without touching another?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov there are a few struct types in my class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you're concerned with concurrent access, you may want to consider making a single object to `lock` against for the whole class, resulting in "any change needs to have exclusive access" behavior. This depends on how ok you are with the performance hit of every write waiting on a single write, and how often different properties change at once or rely on each other's values.

Another solution is write a wrapper type, and for each underlying `private *** _value` field, wrap it in said wrapper, which can handle a single-lock-per-object, allowing minimal duplication of code with the same duplication of performance. this will, however, require each property to have an explicit body and underlying field, rather than letting the compiler do the work, so be aware of that trade-off. Also be aware that by wrapping it in a `class` using this could subtly change some of the behavior of value types, though a simple pass-in pass-out like this shouldn't see any such effects.

```
class ConcurrencyWrapper<T>
{
    priavte object _lockObject = new object();
    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { lock(_lockObject) return _value; }
        set { lock(_lockObject) _value = value; }
    }
}
```

As pointed out by @Patrick Hofman (see comments), you can also utilize a dictionary of lockable objects, and access them according to the name of each property via the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> lockDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
private object GetLock([CallerMemberName] string name)
{
    return lockDict.GetOrAdd(name,
        (key) => new object());    // Using a lambda here prevents evaluation each time the dictionary is queried
}
...
private string _someProperty;
public string SomeProperty
{
    get { lock(GetLock()) return _someProperty; }
    set { lock(GetLock()) _someProperty = value; }
}
```

Finally, if you have lots of concurrent read access but only a few writes, take a look at the [ReaderWriterLockSlim class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx), as this allows for concurrent reads but singular writes. Be aware this will require more verbosity than `lock(_lockObject)` because you'll need to perform the entire `try { } catch { } finally { }` setup yourself.

Comment: An option is to use an internal `Dictionary` for the values, having one `lock` for changing a value (implement the locking in the `this[]` accessor.

Comment: This would result in extra keys each time the property changed values, or else keys relying on the string name of the property (subject to errors when properties are changed in source) or based on reflectively getting the PropertyInfo (subject to the limitations of reflection). It would technically work, but I still think a `Wrapper<T>` is more elegant for keeping a range of locks - at least until we get the `nameof()` operator

Comment: Note that the answer does not address what "thread safe" means for OP - there are barely any cases when changing single property actually can be "not thread safe" by itself - in most cases the problem is multiple properties together are representing some state and changing one of them from other thread would make state inconsistent...

Comment: @Aravol: You can use the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` already.

Comment: That you can! I was under the impression this involved `System.Reflection`, but was mistaken. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: The addition of `CallerMemberName` does make this interesting. I like all the different ways to go about this.

Comment: Looking at the GetLock function, is it possible that 2 threads are at the point of evaluating the Contains to false. One will then set `lockDict[name] = new object();`, the other thread then may try to also do the same. Is this possible?

Comment: This shouldn't be possible, because `ConcurrentDictionary` is guaranteed thread-safe.

Comment: Nope, it may be possible because those are different calls. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: GetOrAdd isn't allowing that lambda expression. Why would you need that anyway? I think return lockDict.GetOrAdd(name,  new object()); would be fine, wouldn't it?

Comment: Relatively fine, since you're instantiating an empty object, but doing so every time may have more performance impact than passing a constant lambda (also, I like lambdas). It's the kind of subtlety that would take extensive testing to prove one way or the other. As for not accepting it, it would seem I failed to take a parameter! I'll update once more